# Setting the background of my textView as a color from 3 integers

Tags: java, android, button, textview, center

```
    public void changeColor(){

    TextView changeColorText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    changeColorText.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF0000);

}
```

My goal here is to take 3 integers and make them into a color. I see that its put into hexadecimal number and the one that I have outputs red. So does this mean with the three integers that I have, i have to convert them into hex? If so how would i convert decimal into hex? Ive researched a few ways to do this, but none of them seem to be what i'm looking for. I have 3 integers so far that only go up to 255, which i assume is correct. Is there an equation that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the three integers that you have are the RGB (Red Green Blue) i presume. Since they go unto 255. Try  this

`changeColorText.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255,0,255)); //sets the color to purple`

1. Red 255
2. Green 0
3. Blue 255

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set the background with RGB. Try something like this :

```
changeColorText.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(r, g, b));
```

Where r g and b are your color values (red, green, and blue). I'm assuming the number's your pulling are RGB values as each one is a set number between 0-255